# Why collapse layout? while page scale up or down

Tags: css

First, I'm sorry to lack my English grammar skills. I'm doing clone coding one of Korean corporation website. but happened problem. Why collapse layout, while page scale up or down?
Especially, `<li>` tag, `<a>` tag under the `gnb` class.
Thank you for understanding although it is not enough grammar.
I hope to more communication. If my english skills grow more.

```css
/*no reset css here.*/
nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 160px;
    background: #0e3c84;
}
#nav, 
#header,
#visual{
    position: relative;
    width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto; /*중앙정렬*/
}

#nav{
    background: #0e3c84;
    height: 160px;
    text-align: center;
}

#nav .prev,
.next,
.control,
.close{
    position: absolute;
}

#nav .prev{
    left: 0;
    top: 42px;
}

#nav .next{
    right: 0;
    top: 42px;
}

#nav .control{
    left: 0;
    bottom: 11px;
    font-size: 0;
}

#nav .control a{
    margin-right: 15px;
}

#nav .close{
    right: 0;
    bottom: 4px;
}

#nav .close label{
    margin-right: 22px;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #fff;
} 

/* 헤더 영역 */

#header{
    height: 100px;
}

header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 99px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c5c5c5;
}

#header h1 a{
    display: block;
    width: 211px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 22px;
    background: url('index_images/h1_logo.gif') no-repeat;
    color: transparent;
}

#header > *{
    float: left;
}

#header ul li{
    float: left;
    padding: 0 16px;
}

#header ul li a{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 96px;
    line-height: 99px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

#header ul li a:hover{
    background: url('index_images/bg_lnb.gif') no-repeat center 87px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #1764dc;
    color: #3c91f3;
}

/* 헤더 영역 고객센터 */

#header div{
    float: right;
    padding: 30px 0;
    font-size: 0;
}

#header div a{
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #0e3c84;
}

#header div a:nth-child(2){
    display: inline-block;
    width: 75px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 11px;
    background: url('index_images/bu_arrow_down.gif') no-repeat 55px 19px #2cc06b;
    font-size: 9px;
    text-indent: 9px;
    line-height: 42px;
    color: #fff;
}

#header  div a span{
    color: #1764dc;
}

/* 비주얼 영역 */

.visual{
    height: 631px;
    background: url('/index_images/bg_visual.jpg');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <title>신대구부산고속도로주식회사</title>
</head>

<body>
    <nav>
        <div id="nav">
            <h2 class="hide">배너영역</h2>
            <a href="#"><img src="/index_images/ad_top.jpg"
                    alt="민자고속도로 무정차통행료 시스템 이용방법 중간정차없이 한번에 OK! 민자고속도로 무정차통행료 시스템을 소개합니다."></a>
            <a class="prev" href="#"><img src="/index_images/btn_arrow_left.png" alt="이전영역"></a>
            <a class="next" href="#"><img src="/index_images/btn_arrow_right.png" alt="다음영역"></a>
            <div class="control">
                <a href="#"><img src="/index_images/btn_pause.gif" alt="일시정지"></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="/index_images/bu_paging.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="/index_images/bu_paging_on.png" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="close">
                <label for="chk1"><input id="chk1" type="checkbox"> 오늘 하루 열지 않기</label>
                <a href="#"><img src="/index_images/btn_close.png" alt="배너닫기"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <header>
        <div id="header">
            <h1><a href="#">신대구부산고속도로주식회사</a></h1>
            <h2 class="hide">대메뉴</h2>
            <ul id="gnb">
                <li><a href="#">실시간 교통안내</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">여행정보</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">고속도로안내</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">알림마당</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">참여마당</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">교통안전</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">회사소개</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div>
                <a href="tel:1688-7003">1688-<span>7003</span></a>
                <a href="#">popup</a>
                <a href="#"><img src="/index_images/btn_search.gif" alt="검색하기"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="visual">
        <div id="visual">
            <h2 class="hide">비주얼영역</h2>
            <div class="copy">
                <div>대구<img src="index_images/bu_arrow.gif" alt="왕복"> 부산<br>주행시간 30분 단축</div>
                <div>minute<div>30</div>
                </div>
                <div>MORE</br>FAST사람과 안전을 생각하는 길</div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <a href="#"><img src="index_images/btn_down.png" alt="실시간교통현황 바로가기"></a>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="index_images/bu_paging2.png" alt="첫번째 이미지"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="index_images/bu_paging_on2.png" alt="현재 두번째 이미지"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="index_images/bu_paging2.png" alt="세번째 이미지"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="index_images/bu_paging2.png" alt="네번째 이미지"></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src="index_images/bu_paging2.png" alt="다섯번째 이미지"></a></li>
            </ul>
            <p><a href="#"><img src="index_images/btn_pause2.png" alt="일시정지"></a></p>
            <div>
                <h2>12월<br>행사</h2>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">2016-11-04~ 2017-02-28<br>청도 프로방스 크리스마스축제</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">2016-12-04~ 2017-01-01<br>김해세계크리스마스문화축제</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div>
                        <a href="#"><img src="index_images/btn_arrow_up.png" alt="이전 리스트"></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="index_images/btn_arrow_down.png" alt="다음 리스트"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <h2>날씨</h2>
                    <div>
                        <h3>밀양</h3>
                        12.27 TUE<br>7℃
                        <img src="index_images/ico_weather1.png" alt="맑음">
                        <a href="#"><img src="index_images/btn_arrow_left2.png" alt="이전날씨"></a>
                        <a href="#"><img src="index_images/btn_arrow_right2.png" alt="다음날씨"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's corrected. .gnb class to ---> #gnb id

Comment: What is collapsing? The fiddle looks just fine to me.

Comment: What is your os? I use mac os. but I resolve! that only happens to me.